# Вид шаблона в джумла

Tags: joomla

В шаблоне не отображается категория материала, а мне нужно, чтоб в каждом материале отображалась категория, что делать?

Answer (score 1):

В шаблоне есть папочка html там шаблоны компонентов, найти com_content и для определенного шаблона - вы не сказали где именно в шаблоне не выводится вставляете 
    <?php echo $this->item->category?>

Comment: шаблон называется Gk_news

Comment: ну задавайте же вопрос более конкретно, получается пальцем в небо, люди не понимают где надо категорию выводить и не поймут, то что вы назвали название шаблона это не значит, что все сразу сели и начали по своему усмотрению выставлять в шаблоне ссылки на категории потому-что вы так спросили. Тем более, что и мой ответ получается неправильный т.к. у вас там оказывается К2 компонент для вывода контента кроме того еще куча всяких, где именно вам не выводятся категории?